# "The system cannot find the path specified" error while running pySpark from command prompt

Tags: python, pyspark

I was able to successfully install jdk, spark, scala and hadoop and set the environment variables. I imported the pyspark and SparkSession into my notebook. But while creating a session I got the error saying:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
```

This was the code that I used to create the session.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
```

To resolve this I tried a few things. I came across this code, post which I am unable to run spark on my command prompt or import into notebook.

```
import os
print(os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME"))
print(os.path.join(os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME"), './bin/spark-submit.cmd'))
```

I have tried resetting the environment variables but it did not work. I also tried reinstalling pyspark from command prompt which did not work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the error. Also added the code part that was gave the error

Comment: any luck? having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today. What I did to make the error go away was I changed JAVA_HOME from ...jdk8\1.8.0_301 to ...jdk8\latest.